# I want to send mail through ASP.NET but error occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, smtp

I am using C# for the back end of this contact form and html is the front end

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
   using System.Net.Mail;

   public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
         protected void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              try
              {
                   MailMessage message = new MailMessage(From.Text, To.Text, Subject.Text, Body.Text);
                   message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
                   client.EnableSsl = true;
                   // The credentials when I ran the code were correct.
                   client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com","password");

                   client.Send(message);

                   status.Text = "Mail was sent successfully";
                   status.Text = "Send was clicked";
              }
              // This catch block is so that you can see what error 
              // occurs if there is an error
              catch(Exception ex)
              {
                 status.Text = ex.StackTrace;
              }
       }
 }
```

This is the error that was shown

> System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
>
> at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at index.Send_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\robert.crider\source\repos\WebSite2\WebSite2\index.aspx.cs:line 37

Comment: This is the error that  was shown
 System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at index.Send_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\robert.crider\source\repos\WebSite2\WebSite2\index.aspx.cs:line 37

Comment: could you show the ex.Message or ex.InnerMessage for more error details?

Comment: I don't have a ex.message or ex.innermessage?

Comment: your error catch "catch(Exception ex)" it should have ex.Message or ex.InnerException.Message on it. like your show stack trace ex.StackTrace

Comment: also the stack trace show error on index.aspx.cs:line 37.. could you show what code you have on line 37.

Comment: Use a messagebox to show (ex.Message)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under the question to add any addition details such as the error message, rather than in the comments.

Comment: Okay I will try that and the code that is one line 37 is the send button

Comment: client.Send(message);

Answer (score 2):

be sure you use the right port for google smtp and delivery network. and You already **enable** IMAP and/or POP3 access in the Gmail account settings.

```
SmtpClient client= new SmtpClient
        {
           Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
           Port = 587,
           EnableSsl = true,
           DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
           Credentials    = new NetworkCredential(yourgoogleemail, yourgooglepassword),
           Timeout = 3000
        };
```

Comment: I just enabled Imap and POP3 but still getting the same error with the changes

Comment: Just got it working with the code you provided. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: @RobertCrider - In that case you should accept the answer as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).